# segmentation fault pro*c code for database connection

Tags: unix, oracle-pro-c

I wrote simple pro*c program to check database connectivity.  The code is :

```
int main()
{
    char *conn_string = "IDA/IDA@DBISPSS";
    int x = 10;
    printf("value of x is before db connection %d\n",x);
    printf(" conn_string %s \n",conn_string);
    EXEC SQL CONNECT :conn_string;
    EXEC SQL SELECT 1 INTO :x FROM DUAL;
    printf("value of x is %d\n",x);
    return 0;
}
```

Following commands I executed to create exectuable (test_connection) of pro*c code

```
proc test_connection.pc

cc -I${ORACLE_HOME}/precomp/public -c test_connection.c
cc   test_connection.o   -o test_connection -L$ORACLE_HOME/lib -lclntsh
```

and when I executed test_connection exe,the output is

```
value of x is before db connection 10
conn_string IDA/IDA@DBISPSS
Segmentation fault
```

But the same code workes well in another linux machine and solaris machine.

Why segmentation fault is thrown?

Answer (score 4):

I tested in HPUX 11.11/Oracle 11 and work ok. I don't see any problem, but try some changes:

1. Declare 'x' into a DECLARE SECTION:

   ```
   EXEC SQL BEGIN DECLARE SECTION;
   int x = 0;
   EXEC SQL END DECLARE SECTION;
   ```
2. Try this connection command:

   ```
   EXEC SQL BEGIN DECLARE SECTION;
   char *user = "abc", *password = "123", *database="base";
   EXEC SQL END DECLARE SECTION;
   EXEC SQL DECLARE BASE_HANDLE DATABASE;
   ...
   EXEC SQL CONNECT :user IDENTIFIED BY :password AT BASE_HANDLE USING :database;
   ...
   EXEC SQL AT BASE_HANDLE SELECT 1...
   ```
3. Insert a `printf("here 1");` between `EXEC SQL CONNECT...` and `EXEC SQL SELECT ...` to see where SEGFAULT is thrown.

Comment: still am getting segmentation fault. but no core file generated. I inserted print statment before and after SQL CONNECT.  The print before SQL_CONNECT got executed but print after SQL CONNECT dint get executed. some problem with SQL CONNECT i guess. but no idea

Comment: its not able t interpret EXEC SQL i think.. what could be the problem?

Comment: Yes. We aren't able to interpret. I'm think about...<br>
Is Oracle's library version same in all systems? Are you coping the binary or recompiling for earch system? I already had problems with lib's versions 9 and 11.

Comment: it works fine on the system where Oracle 11 g is installed that is its database server.  But the problem coming on the machine where we installed oracle 11g client.  Another machine where it works fine is Solaris where oracle 10 g client is used to connect to 11g databse. not sure problem with libraries or not.

Comment: additionally,  on the machine where am getting segmentation fault, am able to connect to database using sqlplus.  so there is no problem from the linux server to db on connnectivity regard.  but pro*c code not working.

Answer (score 1):

I had that problem and no amount of fiddling with my source made any difference.  What finally worked was when I reinitialized all (ALL) my libraries to make sure that Oracle only had access to the 32 bit versions of the library.  It seems Oracle was somehow getting connected to a 64 bit library.  Only by removing all references to any libraries or executables except the 32 bit versions worked.  This included running a 32 bit version of Pro*C.